# Setting Default Parameter In SSRS 2005

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have to set up a report where the user can choose a name from a drop down list. Is it possible to set a default name from the drop down list? So when the report's delivered to the user's email address, the results should be displayed of the default name's results. Is this possible?

I have tried a method to setup a default value but I am not sure if I am doing it correctly. What I did was, Open up Report Parameters and under default values, I selected Non-Queried and entered the Name which I wanted to display, but that did not work

If I am unclear, ask me and I will try my best to explain.

Thank You

Comment: Do you want to pass the name as parameter to report ? Or just use that passed name on the report ?

Comment: Pass the name as parameter to report @CoderofCode

Comment: S o you want available list of names from user can select correct ?

Comment: I want a default value from the list of names. At the moment, there is a drop down box with list of names. From that list, I want a default name. Thanks @CoderofCode

Comment: What do you mean default name ? Is that if user doesn't select any then that default will be used  right ?

Comment: Yesss, thats correct. @CoderofCode

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69440/discussion-between-coder-of-code-and-freddy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are talking about a report being delivered to the user's email, so i suppose you have a subscription set up. if so, you can set the parameter value in the subscription. you will need one subscription per user, and set the parameter in each subscription.

if you want to automate this (have the parameter set depending on the recipient), one option is to use data driven subscriptions (sql enterprise edition).

Comment: So this annot be done within the report manager, but its done when managing the subscriptions? Wow, I did not knwo that. Thanksss

Comment: ARe there any other methods?

Comment: well there is one free tool i wrote, https://busyreports.codeplex.com/, or you can imagine other ways, like generating subscriptions, etc. the problem is that if the reports runs on schedule, it will run under a service account. so all the ssrs functions like User!UserID won't work..